# how can I create a virtualenv variable inside a makefile

Tags: python, linux, bash, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile to compile a full project.

I want to start by creating a virtualenv variable inside it using `mkvirtualenv` wrapper like:

```
train: create_env
    echo "create env?"

create_env:
    ( \
    mkvirtualenv -p python3.6 RC_RSC_env; \
    )
```

but I am getting this error:

```
( \
mkvirtualenv -p python3.6 RC_RSC_env; \
)
/bin/sh: 2: mkvirtualenv: not found
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'create_env' failed
make: *** [create_env] Error 127
```

Comment: You need to figure out why `mkvirtualenv` is not found, maybe its parent directory is not correctly listed in your `PATH` environment variable. Maybe you have it in `bash` but not in `sh`. Could be many things.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `train` target? It looks like it's presenting a prompt, but doesn't ask for any input, and in any case, it will create the virtual environment *before* displaying the prompt.

Comment: @chepner it's just an example.

Comment: With Python3 you usually now have a `venv` module. You might want to consider changing it to `python3.6 -m venv RC_RSC_env` (even though that is not your question). Otherwise like @sinroc mentioned, it's obviously failing running the command. Not sure where the variable comes in?

Comment: @user_007 In that case, it serves no purpose in this question.